# What is the complexity of Array.new(n,x) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the running time of declaring an array with a initial size and a default value ?

Comment: Do you want to know how much time array initialization takes? And as `n` increases what is the initialization complexity/ O(n) ?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it wasn't `O(n)`. Do you have doubts about that @LucasAlencar? Why?

Comment: @spickermann: There is nothing in the Ruby language specification that *guarantees* it, though. In fact, neither the ISO Ruby Language Specification, nor RubySpec, nor the RDocs, nor Programming Ruby, nor The Ruby Programming Language specify *any* kind of performance. This means that it is perfectly possible for a Ruby implementation to implement it with an O(n²) algorithm and be fully compliant with Ruby. Such an implementation probably wouldn't be accepted by the Ruby community, but there are *no guarantees*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: That is true, there are no guarantees. But on the other hand, I cannot think of any naive algorithm for this simple task that wouldn't be in `O(n)`.

Comment: @spickermann: I can: `res = []; n.times { res << x }}; return res` is O(n²) and sufficiently naive that someone might write it that way. Like I said, a Ruby implementation that does this would probably not be accepted by the community, but the question is: who decides what the spec of Ruby is? Are expectations of the community part of the spec or not? It would be much easier, if such performance concerns were documented. E.g. the C++ library specification specifies performance guarantees for all library functions, and conforming implementations must meet those performance guarantees.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks. TIL that the C++ library specification places requirements on the performance of algorithms. Never read about that before. That is interesting and seems very helpful indeed.

Comment: @spickermann: E.g. `sort` specifies: "*Complexity*: `O(N log N)` comparisons, where `N = last - first`." and `stable_sort`: "*Complexity*: At most `N log²(N)` comparisons, where `N = last - first`, but only `N log N` comparisons if there is enough extra memory." (Interesting to note: it specifies an *exact* complexity for `stable_sort`, not merely asymptotic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About constant for small arrays and linear after that.

```
require 'benchmark'

0.upto(9).each do |power|
  elements = 10 ** power
  time = 10.times.map { Benchmark.measure { Array.new(elements, :foo) } }.sum(&:real) / 10
  p [elements, '%f' % time]
end

# [1, "0.000001"]
# [10, "0.000001"]
# [100, "0.000002"]
# [1000, "0.000011"]
# [10000, "0.000038"]
# [100000, "0.000286"]
# [1000000, "0.004231"]
# [10000000, "0.036348"]
# [100000000, "0.404822"]
# [1000000000, "8.454289"]
```

[image]

As for an intuitive explanation:

It basically allocates a continual memory block (*) and writes a representation (pointer) of the object in every individual chunk of memory (one chunk being one array element). This iteration over every chunk leads to the linear complexity.

---

Note that for small memory blocks there may be some optimizations to make it constant.

(*) And for larger blocks the block may not be continual, which leads to worse performance.

---

All of this is most probably more dependent on hardware/OS than Ruby's implementation itself.